# Regex to match an exact number of characters in a string

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm trying to get a match of 9-digit integer number.  The text I'm scanning can be a length of 1-200 character.

The trouble I'm running in to is that I do not want to match if the input has a series of digits longer than 9.  I also need to match if the whole input string is 9 digits.  Or begins or ends with the 9-digit number.

I've tried:

```
d{9}      >  This matches sub-strings longer than 9 digits
d{9}(\D)  >  This works unless the sub-string is at the end since this expects some character after the 9 digits.
```

I have search a lot but I have not found this exact issue.  Any ideas?

Note:  I happen to be working with ColdFusion for this particular issue but I'm hoping that a general regex will do the trick.  If necessary I can code this in CFML.

Comment: Should the number be a word by itself, or can letters be around it? If it's a word, use the `\b` word boundary pattern.

Comment: There can be anything around it except other digits (or nothing around it).  If the input is abd123456789xyz then it is a match.  But abd1234567890xyz is not a match because it has the extra digit.  Abd sdf 123456789[end of line/file] would match.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use alternatives to match a non-digit or beginning/end of the string:

```
(^|\D)\d{9}($|\D)
```